# pip install options "no-cache-dir" and "target" don't work well together?

Tags: python, pip, facebook-prophet

I have found that running

`pip install fbprophet --target=/tmp/foo --no-cache-dir`

gives the following error: `ImportError: No module named pystan`

However if I remove either `--target` or `--no-cache-dir` options then it installs successfully. i.e. both of the following commands are successful:

1. `pip install fbprophet --no-cache-dir`
2. `pip install fbprophet --target=/tmp/foo`

Does anybody know why that's the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is neither in `--target` nor in `--no-cache-dir`. I tried both command in transient empty virtual environments (recreating a venv after every command) and got the error with `pip install fbprophet --target=/tmp/foo`.

I believe the problem is in fbprophet's `setup.py`: it [imports pystan](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/c1a38393828a4f6a80eb01294023f56ac8ad51cb/python/setup.py#L28) during build process without checking that it's available or installing it. I think it could be fixed by copying or moving `pystan` from [requirements.txt](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/c1a38393828a4f6a80eb01294023f56ac8ad51cb/python/requirements.txt#L2) to [`setup_requires`](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/c1a38393828a4f6a80eb01294023f56ac8ad51cb/python/setup.py#L108).

I suspect you didn't get the problem because after `pip install fbprophet --no-cache-dir` you have `pystan` installed globally. Remove everything installed with the 1st command and retry the second one. Or try them in new empty virtual environments.

Send a pull request to fix the problem.

I also think you can install in 2 steps:

```
pip install --target=/tmp/foo --no-cache-dir pystan
PYTHONPATH=/tmp/foo pip install --target=/tmp/foo --no-cache-dir fbprophet
```

Comment: Thanks. Created a pull request to see what the authors think. However there are still two issues:

1) I also ran `pip install fbprophet --target=/tmp/foo` in a new virtualenv and it was (is) successful.

2) I still get the same error with the 2-step installation you suggested (in a new virtualenv). The first `pystan` installation is successful, but installing `fbprophet` still gives the same error of `"ImportError: No module named pystan"`

Comment: correction:  The second issue above was because I had to add `/tmp/foo` to `$PYTHONPATH`. (`pip list` wasn't showing `pystan` after the successful installation.) Once I do that the 2-step installation works. 

Back to your original theory: If I create a dummy package that has 
`setup_requires=['pystan'], install_requires = ['pystan', 'fbprophet']` in the `setup.py` file, shouldn't that also do the trick? It doesn't work either and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry, I have to test my own commands. I updated the answer — added `PYTHONPATH` for the last command; this way `setup.py` knows where from to import `pystan`.